# Can't find XPATH element

Tags: svg, xpath, element

I am dealing with this HTML:

```
<div class="IaVba F1" data-test-target="review-rating">
   <svg class="UctUV d H0" viewBox="0 0 128 24" width="88" height="16" aria-label="4,0 de 5 burbujas">
```

I want to get the attribute "aria-label" from the SVG element. Finding the DIV with "review-rating" works fine in XPATH:

```
element = review.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@data-test-target,"review-rating")]')
```

But if I go to the following element that is the SVG it is not working an I received the error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[contains(@data-test-target,"review-rating")]/svg"}

```
element = review.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@data-test-target,"review-rating")]/svg')
```

If I could position to the svg then I could retrieve the "aria-label" attribute.
Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be there's more than one such divs and not all of them contain an svg element. You could try the plural method `review.find_elements` and iterate the list

Comment: Wondering if the `svg` element is bound to the `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace, even if not declared in the HTML and visible, if the browser is "fixing" that, and then unable to find the `svg` element in no-namespace. Try just looking for the child element `.//div[contains(@data-test-target,"review-rating")]/*` and then you could qualify with a predicate matching `local-name()`: `.//div[contains(@data-test-target,"review-rating")]/*[local-name()='svg']`

Comment: Yes, is that, SVG do have a different behaviour. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

svg elements are in a different namespace than html.
Therefore you cannot use xpath as if they were html-elements.
See [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements) for more clarification

So in your case you would need this xpath:

```
.//div[contains(@data-test-target,"review-rating")]/*[local-name()="svg"]
```

Comment: It could be an option but in this case the svg element lacks the xmlns attribute present on the linked tutorial.